# Regarding AngularJS and datatable combination

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatable

First and foremost, hello! I'm new here.

I've been recently learning AngularJS and web development as I'm working so I apologize for my newbieness. I had stumbled upon a wall of sorts regarding datatable integration with AngularJS. Here's the structure of it:

```
               <table class="datatable table table-hover">   
               <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th ng-repeat="column in columns">          
                            {{column.name}}
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="form in forms | filter : {userName : activeFilter['user name']|rangeDate:activeFilter['range begin']:activeFilter['range end']:'birthDate'">
                        <td class="row-md-1">
                            <span ng-model="approvedForm.userName">
                                {{approvedForm.userName}}
                            </span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="row-md-1">
                            <span ng-model="approvedForm.birthDate">
                                {{approvedForm.birthDate}}
                            </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

I've to mention I make use of the filters on the client side, so they can choose the correct rows. The problem was that upon filtering some users and  row-sorting with datatable, the data would get misteriously duplicated on the view, and I couldn't delete it or whatsoever. To solve it I had to take out the ng-repeat filters and filter with datatable filter support. Does anybody know what might have caused this behaviour?

Btw I'm using angularJS 1.x and datatable 1.10

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your data is duplicating because you bind it twice as the attribute of the HTML element and with handlebars. Remove either `ng-model="..."` attribute or `{{...}}` in your code so it would look like this:

```
<span>
  {{approvedForm.userName}}
</span>
```

as @Shaishab Roy mentioned `ng-model` is not supposed to work with `<span>` so try `ng-bind` instead:

```
   <span ng-bind="approvedForm.userName"></span>
```

Comment: `ng-model=""` will not working for `span` tag. you should use `ng-bind=""`

Comment: hm... then I'm confused how data was duplicated if `ng-model` is not supposed to work there =\

Comment: I'll take that advice, thank you! As I said it was kind of weird, because it only would happen after filteringwith ng-repeat filters, and row sorting with datatables. I'm guessing it was something to do with the filters,because once I took them out and used fnfilter (from datatable) the problem was solved.